# Emulate a HTML <button> press within Ruby

Tags: ruby, web, web-scraping

There's a website that I want to scrape (FWIW it's [svpply](http://svpply.com)) and there's a button that shows up sometimes saying "Show All", it's an HTML `<button>` element. Is there any way to use Ruby to emulate a click of this button, and get the content of the full page that results after clicking that button, since the button reveals more content?

Comment: It depends on what the button does.  Does it run JavaScript?  If it's in a form, share the action for the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Show All" button triggers a javascript ajax request. The only way to automate that is to use a library that can execute javascript. Libraries such as Mechanize and ScrAPI will not work.

What will work are tools that drive an actual browser such as [watir](http://watir.com) and selenium. I installed [watir](http://watirwebdriver.com/)-webdriver and successfully got it to click the button and show additional products.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto 'svpply.com/editors_pick'

#count products
puts b.elements(:xpath => '//li[@data-class="Product"]').count
#=> 30

#Now click button
show_all = b.button(:id => "btn_all")
show_all.click
sleep 4

#count products again
puts b.elements(:xpath => '//li[@data-class="Product"]').count
#=>60
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) can do this nicely for you.

Comment: This will not work on the given button, which kicks off a javascript ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is reloaded when you press the button, you can, otherwise you need something that can parse javascript. If you understand where the website redirects you after pressing the button (even on the same page but with some parameters set, use firebug for this purpose), you can eventually read what you need.